# Problem with using custom models for online prediction in Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am trying to deploy an online prediction model using Cloud ML Engine. The model is a custom model created by the Python package annoy.

I have created the model using the code example provided at https://github.com/spotify/annoy:

```
from annoy import AnnoyIndex
import random

f = 40
t = AnnoyIndex(f, 'angular')  # Length of item vector that will be indexed
for i in range(1000):
    v = [random.gauss(0, 1) for z in range(f)]
    t.add_item(i, v)

t.build(10) # 10 trees
t.save('test.ann')
```

I have also created a predictor class for the model as a predictor.py file

```
import os
from annoy import AnnoyIndex



class MyPredictor(object):
    """An example Predictor for an AI Platform custom prediction routine."""

    def __init__(self, model):
        """Stores artifacts for prediction. Only initialized via `from_path`.
        """
        self._model = model

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
        """Performs custom prediction.
        Preprocesses inputs, then performs prediction using the trained
        scikit-learn model.
        Args:
            instances: A list of prediction input instances.
            **kwargs: A dictionary of keyword args provided as additional
                fields on the predict request body.
        Returns:
            A list of outputs containing the prediction results.
        """

        return [1]

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):
        """Creates an instance of MyPredictor using the given path.
        This loads artifacts that have been copied from your model directory in
        Cloud Storage. MyPredictor uses them during prediction.
        Args:
            model_dir: The local directory that contains the trained
                scikit-learn model and the pickled preprocessor instance. These
                are copied from the Cloud Storage model directory you provide
                when you deploy a version resource.
        Returns:
            An instance of `MyPredictor`.
        """
        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'test.ann')
        model = AnnoyIndex(40) 
        model.load(model_path)

        return cls(model)
```

When I try to run the following command to deploy the model, I get an error.

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create lsh_v11 
--model test_lsh_v1 
--runtime-version 1.14 
--python-version 3.5 
--origin gs://bucket/folder/test.ann 
--package-uris gs://bucket/folder/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz 
--prediction-class predictor.MyPredictor
```

The error is

```
(gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: User-provided package my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz failed to install: Command '['python-default', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/tmp/custom_lib', '--no-cache-dir', '-b', '/tmp/pip_builds', '/tmp/custom_code/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Error code: 0)"
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong and if it's even possible to deploy a model like this in Cloud ML Engine.

Btw, This is the content of the setup.py file I am using to create the tar file.

```
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools import setup                       

setup(
    name='my_custom_code',
    version='0.1',
    scripts=['predictor.py'],
    install_requires=['annoy']
    )
```

Comment: were you able to successfully run ```python setup.py sdist``` and ```gsutil cp```?  Just to make sure, can you check whether ```gsutil ls``` works for the path>

Comment: Hi Lak. Yes, I have succesfully executed both commands: `python setup.py sdist` to create the tar file and `gsutil cp` to copy it to google storage. And `gsutils ls` works as well.

Comment: Then, try running the command that fails, i.e. python3 -m  pip install ...

Comment: Have you enabled "stream logging"? There should be more details in the logs. https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict#requesting_logs_for_online_prediction_requests